# Who is Araragi supposed to look like in this scene?

Tags: monogatari-series

I'm watching one of the Monogatari episodes - Mayoi Jiangshi 2 (Second Season episode 8).

[image: A funny-looking Araragi; subtitled "What's with this creepy guy? He's crying blood and standing straight up."]

In this scene the style Araragi is drawn with changes radically, as does his hairstyle.

The fact that the bloody eyes and seemingly explosive hair look so distinctive makes me feel like I'm missing a reference here.

Comment: i would suggest either the main character from Afro Samurai or that red shirt Samurai in Samurai Champloo (i think his name is Logan or something), but that's just a guess

Comment: I've seen both of those series, but I dunno if that's what this is referring to. Neither of them bleed from their eyes as far as I remember, and Mugen's hair is quite short.

Comment: like i said, just a guess, i haven't seen Afro Samurai or seen all of Samurai Champloo so i couldn't comment on the eyes

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Are you talking about episode 3 (Mayoi Snail) of the original Bakemonogatari season or episode 8 of the second season (Mayoi Jiangshi)?

Comment: @Krazer the second season

Comment: Dunno if it's supposed to look like anyone in particular, but the blood bit happens again later in the episode: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PfKKc.jpg Though the facial expression reminds me of Crying Freeman

Answer (score 8):

This could possibly be a reference to the very obscure series [The Soul Taker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_SoulTaker). The main character, Kyousuke Date, cried blood in few episodes. Here's a picture of him:

[image: Soul Taker Kyousuke]

It's not an exact match, but Akiyuki Shinbo, the director of The Soul Taker, also worked on the Monogatari series, which made me think of this. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiyuki_Shinbo#Filmography).)

Answer (score 4):

In search of a more popular series that had character's crying blood, I came across Saint Seiya

[image]

And it does have some fabulous hair, although not *exactly* like araragi's

[image]

Comment: Seems more plausible than my answer; not only is Saint Seiya much more popular than The Soul Taker, but Nisio Isin seems to have a thing for old shounen fighting series, as he showed when he wrote Medaka Box.